# Vue JS: Pass route param while fetching data from database

Tags: vue.js

I have following code to fetch data from database:

```
data() {
    return {
      users: [],
    };
  },

try {
      let response = Axios.get(`user-profile`, {
        
        params:{
          user_id: 123,
          
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```

But `http://test/my-profile?user_id=123` How can I make it `http://test/my-profile/123` ? I should also be able to console.log(response).

I also want to update users[] array after fetching the data.

Comment: You want to change the query param into path param?

Comment: @MohibArshi Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the template literals and append the user_id as a path param.

```
async function fetchUserProfile(){
  try {
     const user_id = 123;
     let response = await Axios.get(`/user-profile/${user_id}`);
     console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
     console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Will I be able to comsole.log(response)?

Comment: Yeah sure, if you are using async-await. you can just add await in front of `await Axios.get` and console.log the response. Let me update the code.

Comment: I get ` Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'await'.` if I do await

Comment: You need to put `async` on the function first and then you can use `await`. Please check the code once.

Comment: I havve edited my question. Can you please check ?

Comment: do you want to fetch the user profile on the component mount ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232347/discussion-between-gaurav-and-mohib-arshi).